# Is there a way to display Image in Linux (remote) console?

Tags: java, linux, image

I am in need to somehow display image on Linux console. Why am I need it?

I need to manually enter CAPTCHA code. However my application runs on remote linux system and I am connecting to it via SSH (Bitwise client). I have thought about writing directly to screen, but hey - I see only "clone" of terminal not the remote terminal itself so this is impossible to achieve. Maybe some kind of Img2Asci converter? Please advise.

Comment: Easiest way will involve forwarding an X session - is that possible?

Comment: Remote system is rented managed server - terminal only, no X available.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming [you can't forward your X session](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-from-ubuntu-machine), perhaps something [like jp2a](http://csl.sublevel3.org/jp2a/), which converts JPEG to ASCII ?

```
convert http://www.google.com/intl/en/images/logo.gif jpg:- | jp2a -           

       .......                                       .':.             
    .::'....':xd.                                     dX'             
  .ld.        ..       .                              oX.          ...
  ;O'              .c;..'cxc    ;,...,c;.  .:'.,lxc.  dX.  ,:'.,dx.. .
  oO.             .ox.    ,x0 .cd.    .cd..ll    l0.  xX. :K,..,::.   
  cxx.      .',cl 'x0      lK'.cx      ;k, lO;  .ll.  dX. o0:         
   ,dkc.      :kd  :kx.   :d;  ,ol.   .lc.  .''lk'    kX'  oOo'...    
     .;:cc;,,',,.    .;;,'..     .,,'...   ''',:lxo. .','.  .,::;.    
                                         .oc.     dO                  
                                          lk;....'c'                  
                                            .'....
```

Comment: I thought about it as i pointed it out in question. Seams like that would be the only possible way. I cannot use jp2a because i need pure java. I have another piece of code however and running tests right now.

Comment: If your solution is in Java you can spawn a new subprocess, of course. Not nice, though

Answer (score 3):

You want to forward your X session.

on the remote system make sure xauth is installed.

on the client system make sure an X client is installed (Xming for windows)

Connect with ssh -X from a command line or with putty enable X forwarding.

You can then either use `display filename` or most applications that so that sort of thing will pop up if a display is detected

Comment: I cannot forward X - remote system is rented managed server without X installed.

Comment: you dont need x installed, you need xauth installed.

Comment: but if I dont have X nor any other window manager installed than how can I forward it (and use AWT at least)? I am not a linux specialist and I feel confused.

Comment: what OS is on there ?

Comment: Debian GNU 6 2.6.32-5-amd64

Comment: `apt-get install xauth`

Comment: ofc. no root/admin etc permissions. Only restricted user.